# Google play store app signing key issue with 105 char hex

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore, jar-signing

I'm trying to add my keystore to google play app signing.

The guide mentions

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore = foo.keystore --alias = foo --output = output.zip --encryptionkey = The_Hex_Which_Is_105_Char
```

`The_Hex_Which_Is_105_Char` is a 105 char hex provided by google in the instructions.

which I had to remove the extra spaces to make it to work.

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=my.keystore --alias=myAlias --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=The_Hex_Which_Is_105_Char
```

but running this I get an error:

```
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Hex encoded byte array must have even length but instead has length: 105. Hex encoded string: The_Hex_Which_Is_105_Char
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.fromHex(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:225)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:149)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:110)
```

How should the key be generated? Why does google give me a 105 char hex key and the pepk tool doesn't work with?

Answer (score 1):

There were 3 options

- Have Google create and manage app signature keys (recommended)
- Export and upload a key and a certificate from a Java Keystore
- Export and upload a key and certificate (not from a Java keystore)

I was using option 2 as my keystore was already created.

I got it to work by using the encryptionkey provided in option 3 (136 characters)

- Export and upload a key and certificate (not from a Java keystore)

> ```
>  java -jar pepk.jar --keystore = foo.keystore --alias = foo --output =
>  output.zip --encryptionkey = KeyFromOption3WorksHere136CharactersLong
> ```

Comment: My mistake was that I accidentally didn't copy the entire key from the play console (missed the last character). Your answer got me on the right track, thanks.